# Approval Process Entry Criteria validation messages

Tags: approval-process

Is it possible to create messages to the user telling them why they have not met the Entry Criteria just as you would for a Validation Rule ?

ie : "You cannot Submit this for Approval because the Status is already Approved"

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is basically NO but you can simulate this by adding a formula field to the top of the standard layout that displays a message

```
This object is not ready for approval submission for reason xxx
```

The formula field generates that text via something like

```
"This Foo is not ready for approval submission for reason " &
IF (someConditionUseCase1,'reason1',
IF( someconditionUseCase2,'reason2',
...
))...)
```

More sophisticated strategies involve using jQuery + VF to hide the Submit for Approval button as well

Comment: ah, good idea - and so simple ! The best ideas are usually the simple ones ! Thanks crop !

Comment: And if you use an image formula, it will pop out to the user so it is less likely to be ignored

Comment: I am just now getting to this and I'm having a problem figuring out the best way to display a list of reasons a user can't submit a record. In other words, I'm trying to say "You can't submit this because : REASON1 ; REASON 2 ; REASON3....". What would be the best way to make the field display a list ? I can't figure out the proper formula for that. Thanks again.

Comment: You could a) have formula fields representing the  each canned response.  Or b) you can use the concatenation operator '&' to build up a list of reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible option for this is create two layouts; one which includes the submit for approval button and one that doesn't.  Create a field update which changes the record type based on the criteria for a complete form.  You could also use the formula field idea to create a message that says the application is not yet complete, (if record type = incomplete, application is not yet complete etc)  User will fill out the form, save, and if it is complete, they will have the submit option on the next screen.