# How to check which criterias are not met while submitting for Approval?

Tags: approval-process

When we try to submit an record for approval, it shows the criteria are not met, but it doesn't show which criterias are not met. How can we find which criteria are not met by the particular end user on the record?

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/104916/approval-process-entry-criteria-validation-messages?rq=1

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4627/how-to-customize-the-error-message-thrown-by-approval-process?rq=1